# Zend Framework join

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join

I've been struggle for hours with the follow join issue in Zend Framework.

My table(s)

- Table (websites)

  - id
  - user_id
  - website
  - url
  - ...
- Table (users)

  - id
  - username
  - salt
  - password
  - ...
- Table (reviews)

  - id
  - website_id (id of website)
  - user_id (id from the user/owner of the website)
  - reviewer_id (id from the user who has reviewed the website)
  - review
  - ...

**What do I want to get..**
To make a array with join of the review and user data is no problem, but I want also
add the website compare to the review.

I made the follow join but I won't work like I want, I have just 3 test reviews in my database and I'm getting over 12 results in my array.

My query:

$select = $this->_db->select()
        ->from('reviews')
        ->joinLeft('users', 'reviews.reviewer_id = users.id')
        ->joinLeft('websites', 'reviews.user_id = reviews.user_id')
        ->where("reviews.user_id = $user_id");

$result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);

With kind regards,

Nicky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a groupBy to your query (untested)

```
$select = $this->_db->select()->from('reviews')
                              ->joinLeft('users', 'reviews.reviewer_id = users.id')
                              ->joinLeft('websites', 'reviews.user_id = reviews.user_id')
                              ->where("reviews.user_id = $user_id")
                              ->group('reviews.id');
```