# Fetching from 2 or more related tables value in Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, parent-child, parameter-passing, zend-db

i'm new to Zend Framework (and new to this forum too :D ) and i find this tricky problem about if you want to fetch from 3 related tables. let's say, if i have these sql query:

> SELECT p.painting_id, p.painting_title
>   ,p.painting_filename,a.artist_name,c.pc_name FROM painting p, artist
>   a, painting_category c WHERE a.artist_id=p.artist_id AND
>   c.pc_id=p.pc_id;

and i want to do this too:

> SELECT p.painting_id, p.painting_title
>   ,p.painting_filename,a.artist_name,c.pc_name FROM painting p, artist
>   a, painting_category c WHERE a.artist_id=p.artist_id AND
>   c.pc_id=p.pc_id AND p.painting_id= $p_id;

**the case is, first, i want to display all paintings (with artist name and category), then, when the user click the painting, it will go to another page and display that painting only (with artist name and category also).**

i have made this progress in models:

class Application_Model_DbTable_Painting extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

```
protected $_name = 'painting';
protected $_referenceMap    = array(
    'Artist' => array(
        'columns'           => array('artist_id'),
        'refTableClass'     => 'Artist',
        'refColumns'        => 'artist_id'
    ),
    'PaintingCategory' =>array(
        'columns'           => array('pc_id'),
        'refTableClass'     => 'PaintingCategory',
        'refColumns'        => 'pc_id'
    )
    );
```

class Application_Model_DbTable_Artist extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

```
protected $_name = 'artist';

protected $_dependentTables = 'Model_DbTable_Painting';
```

}
s

class Application_Model_DbTable_PaintingCategory extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

```
protected $_name = 'painting_category';

protected $_dependentTables = 'Model_DbTable_Painting';
```

}

What kind of function should i add in the model and what should i write in the controller and view script to get result like the SQL query i wrote above ? tell me if i've made mistake.

i will really appreciate if you would give me some example related to my problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar question and it might help you:

[Zend Framework join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663751/zend-framework-join)

Apart from it you can also [write and execute SQL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html) statements directly in Zend Framework.

Comment: hi, thanks ! i manage to get it with write and execute SQL statements directly in Zend Framework. my biggest mistake is i forgot to put the $this->escape to the link  to display current painting(this caused the parameter passing failure) :)) .